# How to display an array of object without knowing the data model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've an array of objects and this is my object structure:

```
[{
  "_index": "bank",
  "_type": "account",
  "_id": "25",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "account_number": 25,
    "balance": 40540,
    "firstname": "Virginia",
    "lastname": "Ayala",
    "age": 39
  }
}, ... ]
```

I need to eliminate **_index**, **_type**, **_id**, **_score** (just displaying **_source**) and I would like to display ahead of each key an input which contains the value:

**account_number**: **[25]**

**balance**: **[40540]**......

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl_hits.data | limitTo: row._index+row._type+row._id+row._score">
      <td> {{row.key}} : 
          <input type="text"
          ng-value="row.value">
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

NW: I know, I'm writing stupid code, just for one reason, to explain my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do `ng-repeat="(key,value) in row._source"`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl_hits.data | limitTo: row._index+row._type+row._id+row._score">
      <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in row._source">
          {{key}} : 
          <input type="text" ng-model="row._source[key]">
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you must use map function for arrays to eliminate unuseful data(_index,_type,etc) and keep the _source.

if x is your array of objects then ctrl_hits.data will have an array with the _source object of your previous data.

```
ctrl_hits.data=x.map(function(e){
    return e._source;
})
```

Then at your html

```
 <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl_hits.data">
          <td ng-repeat=(key,value) in item>              
            {{key}} : <input type="text" ng-model="value"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```